# sum top 80% and count on how many customers make it up

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to build a sales query for a rolling 12 months.  I know my sales by customer, and my total sales.  I'm trying to sum up the top 80% of sales $ and give a count on how many customers make up that 80%.  Any ideas?  I have a result set that looks like the below. Thanks in advance!

```
Customer    Sales       TotalSales      PercentOfSales
8585        19788.81    769658.68       0.03
8429        19598.26    769658.68       0.03
2837        19431.29    769658.68       0.03
6071        19398.11    769658.68       0.03
5027        19223.13    769658.68       0.02
6677        19204.90    769658.68       0.02
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have similar issue, only difference is i'm using Hive. i'm not sure if you've tag your question properly, think it's more than a sql-server-2008 issue.

my solution is:

1. query (use sql) all the records in order of desc.
2. loop all the records (use any other program languages) to accumulate the value of sales, and put the current customer into a list (say "VIPList")
3. loop stops when accumulated value is >= the 80% of total value

then all the customer in the VIPList that are what you wanted.